# How to write integration test cases for ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-node

I am new to substrate and ink, while following [ink documentation](https://use.ink/) I got to the [testing part](https://use.ink/basics/contract-testing) and want to write integration tests. Can someone help me with it or point to the documentation or resources for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do the integration test of ink! project is to use [Typechain](https://github.com/Brushfam/typechain-polkadot).

There are numerous typechain examples in the [SwankyHub](https://github.com/swankyhub) .